# Python websocket closes after few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, websocket

I am try subscribe API http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/

Process how I am doing it.

1. Login (Ok)
2. Subscribe some command (Ok)
3. The data starts coming in (Ok)
4. After few second (cca 20s) (Fail) on:

   ```
     File "/Users/luboshajek/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 122, in recv
   raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException( websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.
   ```

Python or API closes connection :(

inicialize socket:

```
def inicialize(url):
   ws = websocket.WebSocket()
   response = ws.connect(url, receive_limit_ms=1000*3600)
   return ws
```

Every 5s I am sending following ping

```
def ping(): 
  print("Sending ping")
  ws.send(json.dumps({
        "command": "ping",
        "streamSessionId": sessionId
  }))
```

There is a way to open new connection but this approach it's not optimal.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't validating any of the [Validation rules](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#connection-validation).

Comment: I am not sure about `User should send requests in 200 ms intervals. This rule can be broken, but if it happens 6 times in a row the connection is dropped.`
But I tested different settings and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably violated some of [validation rules](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#connection-validation) or I worked with api with  the wrong way.

Anyway I just use library [xapi-node](https://github.com/peterszombati/xapi-node) for nodejs and one of the [wrapper](http://developers.xstore.pro/api/wrappers.html) for other languages.

It solve all my problems.

**I hope that this will be helpful for somebody in future.**